# How to check if the input is only string or characters not in or special char?

Tags: python-3.x

```
students = []

while True:
    Ask = input("Do you Want to Add Student:").lower()
    try:
        if Ask == "Yes".lower():
            student_name = input("Enter Student Name:")
            student_id = int(input("Enter Student ID:"))


            def get_students_titlecase():
                students_titlecase = []
                for student in students:
                    students_titlecase = student["name"].title()
                return students_titlecase


            def print_students_titlecase():
                students_titlecase = get_students_titlecase()
                print(students_titlecase)


            def add_student(name, student_id):
                student = {"name": name, "student_id": student_id}
                students.append(student)

            Ask = input("Do you Want to Add Student:").lower()
            if Ask == "Yes".lower():
                student_list = get_students_titlecase()
                add_student(student_name, student_id)
                print_students_titlecase()
                print(students)
            else:
                continue
        else:
            print("Type Yes if you To Enter The Student Cred".center(50))
    except Exception:
        print("Write Valid Values")
`
```

As in age variable, we have to strictly input numbers only because of the int(). So is there any way for name also. To have only alphabets, not any number or string?

The conclusion should be:

If the input is entered a number or special char in the name it should give Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following two standard `str` functions, the might be what you are looking for:

- [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha): `true` if `str` only contains letters (at least one)
- [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit): `true` if `str` only contains digits (at least one)

You could use them like so:

```
def input_name():
    while True:
        name = input("Enter your name: ")

        if name.isalpha():
            return name

        print("Please only use letters: [a-zA-Z]. Try again.")


def input_age():
    while True:
        age = input("Enter your age: ")

        if age.isdigit():
            return int(age)

        print("Please only use digits: [0-9]. Try again.")


name = input_name()
age = input_age()
```

Comment: It gets a bit longer Code. wait I add my Example Code in above.